# Python: how to store and re-raise exception with original traceback

Tags: python, exception

For debugging, I would like to find out the call trace for a particular method when it was last called before the object has been destroyed.

I came up with this code (which I assumed to be pretty clever):

```
#!python3
import gc
import sys

class TrackGC:
    __slots__ = [ 'is_dirty', 'last_access' ]

    def __init__(self):
        self.is_dirty = False
        self.last_access = None

    def dirty(self):
        self.is_dirty = True
        try:
            raise RuntimeError('last access')
        except RuntimeError:
            self.last_access = sys.exc_info()

    def __del__(self):
        if self.is_dirty:
            sys.excepthook(*self.last_access)

def do_stuff(obj):
    obj.dirty()

obj = TrackGC()
do_stuff(obj)
print("Killing object...")
del obj
gc.collect()
```

I expect that on every call to `dirty()`, the traceback would be saved in the `last_access` attribute, and that the call to `sys.excepthook` in `__del_` would then print this call stack.

In practice, however, I am getting this:

```
$ ./backtrace.py 
Killing object...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./backtrace.py", line 15, in dirty
    raise RuntimeError('last access')
RuntimeError: last access
```

Why is that? I would have expected to see this:

```
$ ./backtrace.py 
Killing object...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./backtrace.py", line 28, in <module>
    do_stuff(obj)
  File "./backtrace.py", line 25, in do_stuff
    obj.dirty()
  File "./backtrace.py", line 15, in dirty
    raise RuntimeError('last access')
RuntimeError: last access
```

Comment: the traceback only contains information in the stack **below** where it was caught, so in this case all you have is the `raise RuntimeError(...)` instead you want to keep the full stack, which can be gotten with the `traceback` module.

Comment: You should convert your comment to an answer as what you said is the right explanation @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen